# How to read the response of a REST api in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am making request to a post API using RestTemplate which will give response as application/json
{
"BuzRules":{
"Id": "1234",
"Unit": "ou12",
"CaId": "abc43"
},
"verifyRule":{
"isValidId": false,
"isValidUnit": true,
"isValidCaId": false
}
}

I need to read the all attributes of verifyRule and if the any of these are false then will set a message that "I'd is wrong, provide correct I'd to verify the rule correctly".

Please provide some working examples.
THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: This is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to define correct DTO in your source code with all the attributes of the answer. And then you can try to accept response in this way `ResponseEntity<DTO> response = 'request code'`.

Or you can just parse given json by `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` in correct DTO class.
It will looks like this: `DTO response = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, DTO.class);`